# Does the boot option acpi=off can overheat my laptop?

Tags: boot, power-management

Help please (excuse my english)

I recently bought an ASUS X453 (quad core intel inside pentium, 4GB RAM, 500GB Disk) and replaced Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.

After a lot of trouble with the install (secure boot, etc.,) I was finally able to use Ubuntu.
However, the first time I restarted it, it froze on the purple screen.

I did a Google search and found a solution which is to boot with the option `acpi=off`. After doing this I can use Ubuntu again!

However, my touchpad does not work (only optical mice), I can't suspend, hibernate, restart or shutdown my machine properly. In addition I noticed that it gets hotter than it originally did when it was running Windows 8.1

UPDATE: 
I am no longer using acpi=off I've tried several others with three different kernels. Funny thing, although a parameter like pci=noapic works fine the first time I use it, the next time it fails. It happen almost every time, I successfully boot to Ubuntu, the first time with a parameter, and the next time I cant.

With paramters acpi_osi=Windows, pci=noacpi, pci=noapic, noapic, acpi=force, acpi=srict
The system started with almost every functionaly (excluding brightness, shutdown, restart, suspend and hibernate)

Comment: did you try "acpi_osi=" ?

Comment: There must be other flag to boot Grub with, the way it is now makes Ubuntu unuseable...

Comment: please post output of "xinput list" and "cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i name" - those command are touchpad related.

Comment: I am no longer using acpi=off I've tried several others with three different kernels. Funny thing, although a parameter like pci=noapic works fine the first time I use it, the next time it fails. It happen almost every time, I successfully boot to Ubuntu, the first time with a parameter, and the next time I cant.